# getting celery group results

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

So this is what i want to do. I have a scheduled task that runs every X minutes. In the task I create a group of tasks that i want them to run parallel to each other. After they all finish i want to log if the group has finished successfully or not. This is my code:

```
@shared_task(base=HandlersImplTenantTask, acks_late=True)
def my_scheduled_task():
    try:
        needed_ids = MyModel.objects.filter(some_field=False)\
                                .filter(some_other_field=True)\
                                .values_list("id", flat=True) \
                                .order_by("id")
        if needed_ids:
            tasks = [my_single_task.s(needed_id=id) for id in needed_ids]
            job = group(tasks)
            result = job.apply_async()
            returned_values = result.get()
            if result.ready():
                if result.successful():
                    logger.info("SUCCESSFULLY FINISHED ALL THE SUBTASKS")
                else:
                    returned_values = result.get()
                    logger.info("UNSUCCESSFULLY FINISHED ALL THE SUBTASKS WITH THE RESULTS %s" % returned_values)
        else:
            logger.info("no needed ids found")
    except:
        logger.exception("got an unexpected exception while running task")
```

This is my_single_task code:

```
@shared_task(base=HandlersImplTenantTask)
def my_single_task(needed_id):

    logger.info("starting task for tenant: [%s]. got id [%s]", connection.tenant, needed_id)
    return
```

This is how i run my celery:
manage.py celery worker -c 2 --broker=[my rabbitmq brocker url]

when i get to the line `result.get()` it hangs. i see a single log entry of the single tasks with the first id but i don't see the others. when i kill my celery process and restart it - it reruns the scheduled task and i see the second log entry with the second id (from the first time the task ran). any ideas on how to fix this?

**EDIT** - so to try and overcome this - I created a different queue called 'new_queue'. I started a different celery worker to listen to the new queue. I want to make the other worker take the tasks and work on them. I think this could solve the problem of the deadlock. 
I have changed my code to look like this:

```
job = group(tasks)
job_result = job.apply_async(queue='new_queue')
results = job_result.get()
```

but I still get a deadlock and if i remove the `results = job_result.get()` line, i can see that the tasks are worked on by the main worker and nothing was published to the new_queue queue. Any thoughts?
This is my celery configurations:
`tenant_celery_app.conf.update(CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'
CELERY_RESULT_DB_TABLENAMES = {
    'task': 'tenantapp_taskmeta',
    'group': 'tenantapp_groupmeta',
}`
This is how i run the workers:
celery worker -c 1 -Q new_queue --broker=[amqp_brocker_url]/[vhost]
celery worker -c 1 --broker=[amqp_brocker_url]/[vhost]

Answer (score 3):

So the solution i was looking for was indeed of the sort of creating a new queue and starting a new worker that processes the new queue. The only issue that i had was to send the group tasks to the new queue. This is the code that worked for me.

```
tasks = [my_single_task.s(needed_id=id).set(queue='new_queue') for id in needed_ids]
job = group(tasks)
job_result = job.apply_async()
results = job_result.get() # this will block until the tasks finish but it wont deadlock
```

And these are my celery workers

```
celery worker -c 1 -Q new_queue --broker=[amqp_brocker_url]/[vhost]
celery worker -c 1 --broker=[amqp_brocker_url]/[vhost]
```

Comment: Have you ever had any issue when waiting for group's results whose subtasks are executed on a different queue? In my case, I can observe subtasks execute successfully but the group fails due to timeout (I have set a timeout). I see you have the same use case here but I'm curious what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

you seem to be deadlocking your queue. Think about it. If you have a task that waits on other tasks, and the queue fills up then the first task will hang forever.

You need to refactor your code to avoid calling `result.get()` inside a task (you probably already have warnings in your logs about this)

I would recommend this:

```
@shared_task(base=HandlersImplTenantTask, acks_late=True)
def my_scheduled_task():

    needed_ids = MyModel.objects.filter(some_field=False)\
                            .filter(some_other_field=True)\
                            .values_list("id", flat=True) \
                            .order_by("id")
    if needed_ids:
        tasks = [my_single_task.s(needed_id=id) for id in needed_ids]
        job = group(tasks)
        result = job.apply_async()
```

That's all you need.

Use logging to track if tasks fail.

If code elsewhere in your application needs to track whether the jobs fail or not then you can use [celery's inspect](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=revoke#inspecting-workers) api.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what i did wrong - Thanks. In your code example, you have `result = job.apply_async()`. if the tasks will run asynchronously, what is the purpose of the result variable? What  information can it give my before the tasks run or finish?